# How can I add a value from a combo box into a text area?

Tags: php, combobox, textbox, sum, shopping-cart

I have to add a kind of shopping cart to a website I'm designing for a web design class where you can select a product from a combo box and then by clicking a button you can add it to a text area and then in a textbox it should show you how much you gotta pay for what you selected but the only thing I've done by now is to show the products in the combo but the adding and the result parts I'm totally lost I would appreciate if somebody helps me with this cause I only got 2 days to finish it or I will flunk the subject

Comment: what have you done by yourself? and can you post your code?

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","paradise_root","gantzminus1");
mysql_select_db("paradise_dbsalon");
$consulta="select precio,nombre from productosyservicios order by nombre asc";
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
$producto=$_POST['combo'];
?>

<?php
 $result= $producto;
 echo $result; 
?>

With this I can by now select the products from the combo but then when I click in the add button instead of adding the name of the prodduct to the text area it adds the price and everytime I add a new one the page refresh and shows the new one but I want them to show like a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your html head

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Assuming your HTML looks like this:

```
<select name="products" id="products">
<option value="phone">Phone</option>
<option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
<option value="shirt">Shirt</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit"/>

<div id="selection"></div>
```

Use jquery to get the value on click event of submit and write that value in selection div:

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(e){

var selected=$("#products option:selected").val();
$('#selection').append("<p>"+selected+"</p>");
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting the products from a table with php does it make any difference? cause I'm doing what you said and its not happening anything

Comment: No populating the products from table does not make any difference. You should reference its value. Make sure you have jquery loaded correctly into HTML page.

Comment: can you show me an example with php? cause I've never used jquery and I'm kinda lost

Comment: Just make sure you include jquery in your page. I have edit the answer to show you how. Also assign appropriate IDs to HTML elements for jquery to work as done in the answer.

Comment: It kinda worked but there's still a problem every time I select a new product instead of adding it down the other the first one dissapears and the new one shows

Comment: Great. Use append(selected) instead of text(selected). Cheers!

Comment: xD kinda again now its showing one next to the other

Comment: lol. I guess you know bit of html. OK use this: append("<p>"+selected+"</p>");

Comment: ok I solved it the problem was in the "</p>" the right way is "\n" I'm almost done now the only thing I need is to show the total ammount of money to pay

Comment: Thats great. If my answer solved your problem then consider accepting the answer. :)

Comment: it solved half of the problem I wonder if you could help me with the last part could you?

Comment: You can create a separate question for that along with your code